# How can I sort a multidimensional array naturally?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array like this:

```
[
    ['number' => '419-1'],
    ['number' => '302-1'],
    ['number' => '102-1'],
    ['number' => '102-11'],
    ['number' => '203-1'],
    ['number' => '508-1'],
    ['number' => '105-1'],
    ['number' => '102-2'],
    ['number' => '302-2'],
]
```

I want output like this:

```
[
    ['number' => '102-1'],
    ['number' => '102-2'],
    ['number' => '102-11'],
    ['number' => '105-1'],
    ['number' => '203-1'],
    ['number' => '302-1'],
    ['number' => '302-2'],
    ['number' => '419-1'],
    ['number' => '508-1']
]
```

Problem is number is stored as string. **I want to treat number as integer. Sorting needs to be done numerically. Not string comparison.** I tried with usort but that did not help.

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are wanting to naturally sort the array values, `1, 2, 10, 20` so they are not sorted as a numeric string `1, 10, 2, 20`. The results of which should be the same in PHP 5 and PHP 7.

You can use [`array_multisort`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php) with the `SORT_ASC` and `SORT_NATURAL` flags, along with `array_column` to retrieve the values to sort by.

### Example https://3v4l.org/BNCe5

*PHP 5.5+*

```
array_multisort(array_column($ar, 'number'), SORT_ASC, SORT_NATURAL, $ar);
var_export($ar);
```

Alternatively you can use [`strnatcmp`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strnatcmp.php) with `usort`.

*PHP 5.3+*

```
usort($ar, function($a, $b) {
   return strnatcmp($a['number'], $b['number']);
});
var_export($ar);
```

**Result**

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'number' => '102-1',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'number' => '102-2',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'number' => '102-11',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'number' => '105-1',
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    'number' => '203-1',
  ),
  5 => 
  array (
    'number' => '302-1',
  ),
  6 => 
  array (
    'number' => '302-2',
  ),
  7 => 
  array (
    'number' => '419-1',
  ),
  8 => 
  array (
    'number' => '508-1',
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$arr =    [
        ['number' => '419-1'],
        ['number' => '419-11'],
        ['number' => '102-1'],
        ['number' => '203-1'],
        ['number' => '508-1'],
        ['number' => '105-1'],
        ['number' => '102-2'],
        ['number' => '302-2'],
    ];

    usort($arr, function($a,$b){

        $an = explode('-',$a['number']);
        $bn = explode('-',$b['number']);

        if($an[0] == $bn[0]){
            return $an[1]*1 > $bn[1]*1;
        }

        return $an[0]*1 > $bn[0]*1;

    });

    print_r($arr);
```

Comment: This does not sort properly. If I have a element with ['number' => '102-11'], it would come before ['number' => '102-2'']. I wan to sort it numerically.

Comment: I have edited input and output array in question. I don't want to compare them as a string, I need to compare them as number.

Comment: Updated as per your observations.

Comment: Your solutions works too! but I like first answer more as one liner. Thanks!

Comment: @TejasGosai  Indeed.  Yours is slick and that SORT_NATURAL flag is a nice one!